# Access MySQL databases with only root password

Tags: mysql, shell, command-line, passwords, root

so I have a dilemma.  I am taking over from another developer and there's a box to which I only have root access, and I need to download the MySQL database from it.  So I root in, and type `mysql` in the command line and get:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Then, I try `mysql --user=root --password={myrootpassword}` and it says:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I have no other information than the root password.  Obviously this should be enough; how do I access my databases?  Is the solution to create a new MySQL username?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop the mysql daemon, and start it up again with the `--skip-grant-tables` option.  Once it's started up, you'll be able to log in as root with no password.  You can do everything with the databases, change passwords, all that.

Note, you *and everyone else* will be able to log in without a password.  You'll probably want to block off port 3306 or take the machine off the internet altogether til you're done what you need to do.

Once you've gotten the data or changed passwords or whatever, stop the service again and restart it normally to reenable permissions.

Comment: @Brian Here is your answer.

Comment: This was the solution, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

MySQL `root` and server `root` are two different accounts. Even if you have server root access it won't necessarily mean its same as MySQL `root`. However with server root access you can change MySQL root password. Depending upon the administration panel installed on your server there can be many different ways to do that.

Comment: How do I do that?  I'm a complete MySQL amateur.

Comment: Which admin panel you use for server administration? or are you good at command shell?

Comment: There is no admin panel installed.  I have to do this with shell only, which I'm not good at.  That's why I just want to export the MySQL tables and move them onto a new server.

Answer (score 0):

First login as root

```
su root;
```

You can then set password by

```
root paswd;
```

It will ask for password, u can set whichever u wish.
Then logout from their & login as root as Username